# Removing page number from ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, page-numbering

How to remove the page number from the table of contents page?

Answer (score 68):

See [this FAQ answer](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-nopageno). In the simplest case you just use `\thispagestyle{empty}` *after* `\tableofcontents`. However there are several complications, so see the linked answer.

One problem not discussed in the FAQ is if the table of contents is longer than 1 page. For this situation you can write `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}`  somewhere before your first chapter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But could you please edit it to include the actual answer *in the site* and not just point to an external site? See [quality standards for answers](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227/quality-standards-for-answers) for the rationale behind this.

Comment: Just to get your attention, I second Juan's request.

Comment: I have TOC on 3 pages and if I use `\thispagestyle{empty}` after the `\tableofcontents` only the **3rd** page has no page number. Then I add the `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}` in front of the first chapter and I get rid of the page number on the **1st** page while page number on the **2nd** page remains...

Comment: @71GA in that case I guess you can add also `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\pagestyle{empty}}` next to the other `\addtocontents{}`

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41558/5206

Comment: This works only on article

Answer (score 12):

A combination of the following two commands after `\tableofcontents` worked for me:

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What is the difference between your answer and the answer of LeV Bishop? Please explain what your code does ...

Answer (score 3):

i have three pages of table contents and two lists of figures also. the document genrates automtically the number of pages. but we can undisplay the number of pages with the first cmd. then when you want to display the number again use the second cmd

```
\pagenumbering{gobble}
```

then when you want to display the numbers of pages simply type:

```
\pagenumbering{arabic}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! That is already mentioned in another answer!

Comment: This is by far the cleanest answer and I don't see any other answer that provides this solution as succinctly. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

For me worked the following code:

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\input{inc/1.Introduccion}
...
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436). This answer does not add anything to the given answer by Lev Bishop.

Comment: A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the complete solution for multi-page ToC:

```latex
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\pagestyle{empty}}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
```

This also removes the header and footer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `\usepackage{fancyhdr}`,then the `\pagenumbering{gobble}`command is not very effective, for it will "gobble" the Arabic number but left other self-defined info. If you are using `\thispagestyle{empty}` way, or with \protect`macro, there may still be pages incorrect.

I've tried and got a new way to solve the problem.

1. First, we have a basic assumption that the main chapter is form page 1, so you can insert a `\setcounter{page}{1}` on the first page of the document except TOC.
2. Then, we try to determine if the page number equals to the real page number especially after we reset the page number. We use `\usepackage{xassoccnt}` to find the absolute page of the "page", and in the toc part, we know it equals to the real page, but in the main part, it does not.

```
\usepackage{xassoccnt}
\newcounter{realpage}
\DeclareAssociatedCounters{page}{realpage}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \stepcounter{realpage}
}
\newcommand\evifooter{%
\ifnum\the\value{page}=\the\value{realpage}%
\large Toc Page \thepage%If you do not need it, leave blank.
\else%
\large Main Chapter Page \thepage%
\fi%
}
```

3. Third, we use the `fancyhdr` package to make the footer.

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\evifooter}
```

In sum, this way can help deal with all situations in which we need to set header of footer differently.