# Best way to remove page numbers from a TOC?

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering

What is the best way to remove Page Numbers from a Multi-Page TOC without touching the `\pagestyle` or `\thispagestyle`?

I've seen [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9289/table-of-contents-or-toc-lines-without-page-numbers) post already, but I want to find out if there are more ways to solve this.

Furthermore, if you have a collection of "pages", how do you easily nest these inside a block that does not include page numbers?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you don't want to change the page style, you could change the page numbering. For example:

```
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
```

Here, I switched it off by using `gobble`. Note, by `\pagenumbering{arabic}` the numbering starts with 1, so it might be that you would like to raise the page number using `\refstepcounter` or `\addtocounter`, for example.

I used `\cleardoublepage` to end the page before changing the page numbering. Otherwise the last table of contents page could get an arabic number.

You could use this for disabling page numbering in blocks, or consider adjusting the page style in the block, or redefine `\thepage` locally within in the block. If you need `\thepage` though, you could introduce another macro, which is `\thepage` by default and is used in your header or footer, and change that temporarily.

Comment: You rock. But I got a page number on the page before the TOC, but maybe that could be caused by something else?
**Edit**, added a \newpage and it works now, thanks a lot