# Remove page numbers of LoF/LoT in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script

I would like to remove the linked page numbers of the LoF and LoT inside the TOC. The page numbers should start appearing with the first chapter.

```
\documentclass[listof = totoc]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx, duckuments}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

    \hypersetup{pageanchor=false}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{empty}

    \tableofcontents % no page number for lof, lot wanted inside toc
    \listoffigures

    \cleardoubleoddpage
    \pagestyle{scrheadings}
    \renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{plain}
    \hypersetup{pageanchor=true}
    \pagenumbering{arabic}

    \duckument

    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics{example-image-duck}
        \caption{I'm a random duck}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I **don't** mean the actual page number at the bottom. The number I mean is printed on the right handside at the `\tableofcontents`.
[image]

Comment: See this Q&A: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2995/removing-page-number-from-toc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing page number from ToC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2995/removing-page-number-from-toc)

Comment: The linked Q&A shows how to deactive the page number at the page. I want to deactivate the page number shown at *List of Figures* at the *Contents* page

Comment: @AML I've updated my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two suggestions.

You could use a switch in the code for `tocpagenumberformat`

```
\documentclass[listof = totoc]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{duckuments}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hypertexnames=false}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  tocpagenumberformat=\tocchapterpagenumberformat
]{chapter}

\newif\ifgobblechaptertocpagenumber
\newcommand*\tocchapterpagenumberformat[1]
  {{\ifgobblechaptertocpagenumber\else{\usekomafont{chapterentrypagenumber}#1}\fi}}

\begin{document}
\hypersetup{pageanchor=false}
\renewcommand*\chapterpagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{empty}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\gobblechaptertocpagenumbertrue}

\tableofcontents % no page number for lof, lot wanted inside toc
\listoffigures

\cleardoubleoddpage
\hypersetup{pageanchor=true}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\renewcommand\chapterpagestyle{plain}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\gobblechaptertocpagenumberfalse}
\duckument
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics{example-image-duck}
    \caption{I'm a random duck}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or you could define a new entry `listchapter` and patch `\addchaptertocentry` for the lists to use `listchapter` instead `chapter`:

```
\documentclass[listof= totoc]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{duckuments}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  level=\chaptertocdepth,
  indent=0pt,
  numwidth=1.5em,
  pagenumberformat=\gobblepagenumber
]{chapter}{listchapter}
\newcommand\gobblepagenumber[1]{}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\BeforeTOCHead{%
  \xpatchcmd{\addchaptertocentry}{chapter}{listchapter}{}{\addchapPatchFailed}%
}

\begin{document}
\hypersetup{pageanchor=false}
\pagestyle{empty}
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{empty}

\tableofcontents % no page number for lof, lot wanted inside toc
\listoffigures

\cleardoubleoddpage
\hypersetup{pageanchor=true}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{plain}

\duckument
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics{example-image-duck}
    \caption{I'm a random duck}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The result is the same as above.

Comment: Thanks for this great answer. It is working as expected. I'll use the second approach because it seems somehow more clear to me.