# Add unnumbered title of acro to ToC

Tags: koma-script, acro

Coming up from my previous question [Remove page numbers of LoF/LoT in TOC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/440188/remove-page-numbers-of-lof-lot-in-toc) I encounter a new problem using the `acro` package. (switching to `glossaries` is no alternative at this point tome)

I try to add a *unnumbered* ToC entry for my acronyms. The package provide the command `\printacronyms[heading=chapter*]` which produce an unnumbered chapter but no ToC entry. Actually using `\addchap{Acronyms}` would produce the desired result but I'm unable to combine it with the `acro` package.

```
\documentclass[listof = totoc]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{duckuments}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\DeclareAcronym{Team}{
    short = Team,
    long = {Toll ein anderer macht's}
}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
    tocpagenumberformat=\tocchapterpagenumberformat
]{chapter}

\newif\ifgobblechaptertocpagenumber
\newcommand*\tocchapterpagenumberformat[1]
{{\ifgobblechaptertocpagenumber\else{\usekomafont{chapterentrypagenumber}#1}\fi}}


\begin{document}
    \renewcommand*\chapterpagestyle{empty}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\gobblechaptertocpagenumbertrue}

    \tableofcontents
    \listoffigures
    \printacronyms[heading=chapter*]%
    % \addchap{Acronyms} % Desired result

    \cleardoubleoddpage
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \renewcommand\chapterpagestyle{plain}
    \pagestyle{scrheadings}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\gobblechaptertocpagenumberfalse}

    \duckument

    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics{example-image-duck}
        \caption{\ac{Team}}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you try `\printacronyms[heading=addchap]`?

Comment: @clemens Not until you mention it. But your solution is working fine. Thanks

Comment: @clemens do you want to post a (short) answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a KOMA-Script class which provide commands for unnumbered chapters and section with an entry in the TOC: `\addchap`, `\addsec`, …

`acro` allows you to use those:

```
\printacronyms[heading=addchap]
```