# List of figures without page numbers and dots

Tags: table-of-contents

I use texniccenter + miktex for my work.

I want to list all my figures captions (without page numbers, dots and number before figures) in list of figure section. How to do it? Eg. under 'BRIEF DESCRIPTION OF DRAWINGS' section I want to include only the figure captions without displaying the page number, dots, i.e. the pdf output should look like:

BRIEF DESCRIPTION OF DRAWINGS

Figure 1: This is the figure caption for the above figure. It displays usefulness of many quantities for the present data evolution of the fact.

Figure 2: The above figure is very simple graph from a pdf which is may be relevant for the present work.

But latex always shows page numbers with dots!!
Also there should be no space between Figure 1:... and margin.

But what latex pdf shows (which I don't want) is the following:

1  Figure caption text...........2

2  Figure caption text...........3

I want to avoid numbers before 'caption' (1 and 2) and page numbers (2 and 3) on right and dots ...

Second help:

In my DRAWING section it contains only figures with its captions. Here I want 'Figure 1' should be displayed but without caption. How to do it?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headheight}{20mm}
\usepackage[top=4.0cm,bottom=3.0cm,left=4.0cm,right=3.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage[pagewise]{lineno}
\renewcommand\linenumberfont{\normalfont\bfseries\small}
\setlength\linenumbersep{8mm}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\setlength\parskip{2.0ex}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\large\bfseries\sffamily}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{*2}{*0}

\begin{document}

\section*{\centering Some title}
\section*{TITLE: Some time second}
\section*{ABSTRACT}
This is title.
\section*{OBJECT}
Some text goes here~\ref{fig:gra}.
\section*{BRIEF DESCRIPTION OF DRAWINGS}%Figure captions
\listoffigures

\section*{Special heading}
Can include some text.

\pagebreak
\setcounter{page}{1}%drawing page number starts from 1
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\textbf{Applicant name(s): \\Application no.: 123456599}}
\fancyhead[R]{\textbf{\thepage\ Sheet\ of \\\pageref{LastPage} Sheets }}
\fancyfoot[R]{\textbf{Signature\\My Name\\11112}}

\section*{DRAWINGS}
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=110mm]{monomer2}
\caption{This is the figure caption for the above figure. It displays usefulness of many quantities for the present data evolution of the fact.}\label{fig:mono}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=110mm]{sam3}
\caption{The above figure is very simple graph from a pdf which is may be relevant for the present work.}\label{fig:gra}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Thanks
Regards, Raja.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/440188/remove-page-numbers-of-lof-lot-in-toc and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/440188/remove-page-numbers-of-lof-lot-in-toc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an answer to your original question.

```
% lofprob.tex SE 550574
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headheight}{20mm}
\usepackage[top=4.0cm,bottom=3.0cm,left=4.0cm,right=3.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage[pagewise]{lineno}
\renewcommand\linenumberfont{\normalfont\bfseries\small}
\setlength\linenumbersep{8mm}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\setlength\parskip{2.0ex}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\large\bfseries\sffamily}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{*2}{*0}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% code to give what you are after
\usepackage{tocloft} % for fiddling with the ToC, LoF and LoT
\renewcommand{\cftfigdotsep}{\cftnodots} % no dots
\cftpagenumbersoff{figure} % no page numbers
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\fnum@figure}[1]{\figurename\ \thefigure} % remove the : after number
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\section*{\centering Some title}
\section*{TITLE: Some time second}
\section*{ABSTRACT}
This is title.
\section*{OBJECT}
Some text goes here~\ref{fig:gra}.
\section*{BRIEF DESCRIPTION OF DRAWINGS}%Figure captions
\listoffigures

\section*{Special heading}
Can include some text.

\pagebreak
\setcounter{page}{1}%drawing page number starts from 1
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\textbf{Applicant name(s): \\Application no.: 123456599}}
\fancyhead[R]{\textbf{\thepage\ Sheet\ of \\\pageref{LastPage} Sheets }}
\fancyfoot[R]{\textbf{Signature\\My Name\\11112}}

\section*{DRAWINGS}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering 
  MONOMER2
%  \includegraphics[width=110mm]{monomer2}
\caption[This is the figure caption for the above figure. It displays usefulness of many quantities for the present data evolution of the fact.]{}\label{fig:mono}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \centering
  SAM3
%  \includegraphics[width=110mm]{sam3}
\caption{The above figure is very simple graph from a pdf which is may be relevant for the present work.}\label{fig:gra}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

It does what you asked for except for deleting the figure numbers in the LoF, which I think is not a sensible thing to do: how is your reader going to link the unnumbered caption in the LoF with the numbered but non existent caption text in the figures?

Please, when providing an MWE, for which thank you, provide graphics that are generally available, or just plain text.

Comment: Hello, thanks. I am making a template. In patent (Indian) applications, I need to include the list of figures without page numbers and dots, which I solved with your codes (as i posted n the image). And drawing in a separate sheet without caption, but with Figure 1, Figure 2, etc, as the captions will be displayed in list of figures. Anyway I solved it. By using the following code:
`\usepackage[font=small,labelsep=none]{caption}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{FIGURE}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont={bf},name={FIGURE}}
'
and using 
`\caption[The above figure osgood.]{}\label{fig:mono}`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the links. I just solved partially (see code below). It produces what I need (see the image below).
In the code shown below last two lines are used for removing page number and dots. I really don't know the meaning of the codes %1 to %5? Now I need to adjust spacing before Figure 1, Figure 2.Eg. in the image I want to remove the space, so that Figure 1 starts from the left margin.. Also I just want a normal space (~) between 'Figure 1:' and 'This is the figure...' how can I do?
[image]

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\large\bfseries\sffamily BRIEF DESCRIPTION OF DRAWINGS}%list of fig

\newlength{\mylen}%1
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{\figurename\enspace}%2
\renewcommand{\cftfigaftersnum}{:}%3
\settowidth{\mylen}{\cftfigpresnum\cftfigaftersnum}%4
\addtolength{\cftfignumwidth}{\mylen}%5

\cftpagenumbersoff{figure}%remove list of figure page numbers
\renewcommand{\cftdot}{}%no dots
```

Thanks